# No error window in Dev cpp

Tags: c++, ide, dev-c++

I am sorry for this silly doubt.

But when I compile this program, it only shows error line. It does not show error window.

(I have purposely made an error here, I know the correct solution in code ).

I tried view section in menu bar, but couldn't find the solution.

[image]

Any settings help will be appreciated.

Comment: check if there is any `Log` section under `View` or `Window` menu.

Comment: head is a pointer. Try head = &temp;

Comment: @Tracer I quote the OP: "I have purposely made an error here, I know the correct solution in code"

Comment: Go to View and select what window to view

Comment: @Kam every window is selected in View . Still no changes.

Answer (score 31):

No need to be sorry.. it happens..

1. Right click the status bar
2. Click on floating report window.
3. A movable window will come up.
4. Click on the inner tabbed close button. (You may have to right-click the report window to resize it and see the close button)
5. After that just randomly resize the window so that it doesn't hide again.

Happy Coding..!!![image: Error Window]

**Edit** - As @Alex suggested in one comment below -

You probably hid Error window while you were changing it's size. So it's hidden between Editor window and Statusbar. Try to close Statusbar first (right mouse click -> Statusbar) and then stretch Error window to normal size (click and pull lower window bound up).

This also works. :)

Answer (score 7):

1. Click the **"View"** at the top of the window.
2. Then Click on the "**Floating Report Window**".
3. A floating window will appear at the botton of the screen.
4. Then Resize that floating Window.
5. At last click on the inner tabbed close button.

Answer (score 4):

## simple!

1. Goto "***view***" at the top of the window.
2. A whole bunch of options shall drop down.
3. Check "***floating report window***".
4. Thats it!

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. If you restart your devcpp you will see report bar(including compile log). But if you try to click it it will dissapear. The problem is that this window is shrunk in size to a bar. All you need is just after restarting devcpp click and stretch this bar to small size window.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? I did not understand!

Comment: @JayPatel , You probably hid Error window while you was changing it's size. So it's hidden between Editor window and Statusbar. Try to close Statusbar first (right mouse click -> Statusbar) and then stretch Error window to normal size (click and pull lower window bound up).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools menu then select Environment Options
then go to compilation progress area, check the Show during compilation option and uncheck the Auto close after compilation option.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these answers, couldn't find it yet. I tried pressing the F key buttons and it popped up. So all that needs to be done is press F2!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to view
2. Click 'floating report window'
3. A long 'Report Window' bar will come out, just resize it and you'll see the compile log.