# no error window even when I've check view>floating report window in dev c++

Tags: c++, ide, dev-c++

I read the question [no error window in dev c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704270/no-error-wind)  to find the answer to the same problem I was facing. I followed the answer but I'm encountering a further problem as my floating report window has no log space or options. It's just a floating window and I do not know what to do with it.
This is a silly extension to that question, but please help me- I'm stuck for long.

[image: This is my floating report window(and I've right-clicked on it]
[image: with active toolbars]

Comment: Seems like you are missing a toolbar as well. I have not used this in decades so I can't help.

Comment: Can you not drag the bottom of the title bar down?

Comment: @drescherjm I have added toolbars ( all of them ) , see if you remember anything

Comment: I think you want to click on the "Size" on the context menu you show.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks a lot, that worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you check the view>floating report window option , you have to right click on the floating window and click resize option and drag the floating window down . 
And you will be able to see your lost error window again. [image]